# Upgrade without ubuntu-release-upgrader

Tags: apt, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I want to upgrade from 16.10 to 17.04 and `sudo do-release-upgrade` fails due to `An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.` (and nothing else). My point of view here is that this is ridiculous feedback for an important system component and I requested improvement at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1684198.

I know the Ubuntu bug triaging process and filed dozens of bugs and I know that probability that this will be resolved (shouldn't be too hard and would help a lot of people and save Ubuntu from massive reputation loss) are very small. I don't have resources to step in within a realistic time.

So, my options are:

- figure out what the problem could be: probably not so hard, but I feel bad allowing bad feedback and programmers laziness to put pressure on me
- do a release upgrade by deactivating all PPA, changing `yakkety` to `zesty` in `sources.list` and upgrade with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-ugprade` like Debian untu does
- reinstall the system: everything works fine in 16.10 - for Ubuntu standards - and it's not worth having only an updated version

Is the second option wise on Ubuntu 16.10 (and other versions in general)?

Comment: "An unresolvable problem" is indeed annoying feedback, but the underlying problem is not caused by programmer laziness. Unresolvable apt  situations usually refer to SOMETHING YOU CAUSED. Attempting a release-upgrade while your system is in this condition is sheer folly, and commonly results in a thoroughly broken system. Figure out the problem you caused, and fix it.

Comment: I was referring to programmers laziness by him_her evaluating a logical condition that determines whether the system is operational or not and then not incorporating this logical condition into the error message. I know that it's my fault that the system can't upgrade, but it's the fault of the programmer that I can't trivially fix this state.

Comment: There should be logs in the `/var/log` directory like syslog and apt related ones as well as potentially one for the release upgrade which should help you diagnose the problem. I am afraid that I am on Arch and the virtualisation program I use is playing up so I can't get access to an Ubuntu system at the moment to be more specific in my advice.

Comment: Another alternative would be to do a fresh install of the new system.

Comment: Merely deactivating a PPA is sometimes not enough. A conflict is not caused by a *source*, it's caused by packages provided by that source. Changing the release-upgrade method won't eliminate the conflict, and (again) may break your system quite horribly. The  best advice is to uninstall *all* packages provided by non-Ubuntu sources before starting a release-upgrade. This is also known as 'returning your system to as close to stock condition as possible'.

Comment: There should be more helpful error messages in `/var/log/apt`.